# What is the minimum spec PC to watch BBC HD on BBC iPlayer?

Tags: hdtv

I have a an AMD64 3000+ (socket 939) and a nVidia FX5200 (AGP) and it is struggling to play HD content from BBC iPlayer, the picture is quite jumpy. **So I am wondering what is the minimum spec PC to watch BBC HD on BBC iPlayer?**

Answer (score 1):

They likely use Adobe Flash. If so......

[Adobe Flash HD Requirements](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/systemreqs/)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question, but also thanks to M4dRefluX for the info.

So it seems BBC iPlayer is in fact using Adobe Flash Player and seems to be more tied to CPU performance than graphics card.

I checked my processor and it was max'ed, running at 100% while playing.

I just did a 10% overclock of the bus from 200Mhz to 220Mhz (taking my CPU from 1800Mhz to 1980Mhz) and now the CPU is bouncing from 98% upto 100% during playback. So I am pretty close it seems.

My guess is at 2.2Ghz (i.e. an AMD 3400+) things would be OK, which does seem to correspond to the Adobe recommendations for 720p.

Comment: Please edit your question instead

Comment: Adobe Flash is a resource hog. Hopefully the open video standard will take over in the next few years.